# How can I train my guinea pigs to not attack one another?

Tags: behavior, training, multi-pet-families, guinea-pigs

I own 2 female guinea pigs. I came home one day to find that one of them had a large amount of blood coming out of its ear. There is nothing in the cage that would produce that amount of blood besides the other guinea pig, so I think it would be safe to assume that one attacked the other. I have also noticed their behavior in the past, and they appear to get along some of the time, and they dislike each other at other times.

I don't really have the resources to separate them, and I want them to be able to live together. I am also a busy enough person that I am unable to be around the cage monitoring their behavior constantly. I am not sure if it is possible to train a guinea pig, and if it is, I don't know how to do that.

How can I train my guinea pigs to not attack one another, without being around the cage constantly?

Comment: Can you edit this question to identify if they are spayed, if so how long ago, how long the two have been together, and if newly paired, what bonding technique you used.

Answer (score 10):

The second easiest way of eliminating fights is increasing their space i.e. give them a bigger cage. How big depends on the guinea pigs in question, but it needs to be big enough to fit at least one house per pig, and preferably one food bowl and one water bottle per pig as well.

The easiest way to stop female guinea pigs from fighting is to introduce a neutered male. Preferably a secure and dominant one.

I do not believe you can train the pigs not to fight - they disagree about who's the boss and/or how that role should be managed. And I do not think neutering is the answer, it is quite risky to spay female pigs and nothing I would recommend.

Answer (score 6):

Spay is the first and best step.  You have two females living in a small space, both anticipating that some day they will have babies and anticipating that there will be competition for scarce space and food.

Spaying will help to eliminate the hormones that cause this friction between your two girls.

Comment: What if they are already spayed?